# Drop down submenus getting hidden behind iframe on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, drop-down-menu

I have a slideshow that uses an iframe from slideful.com. The slideshow from slideful uses jquery. After putting the slideshow on the homepage, I then added in a drop down menu in the navigation, which is directly above the "slideful.com" slideshow/iframe. When I hover over the menu, the submenus get hidden behind the slideful.com slideshow/iframe. I've tried adding the "z-index" attribute, as well as "position:absolute;" but nothing is working.

**The slideful.com slideshow/iframe code looks like this:**

```
<iframe src="http://slideful.com/v20130725_0935361299097223_pf.htm" frameborder="0" style=" border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;width:900px;height:563px;position:relative;z-index:1000;" allowtransparency="true">
```

**The code for the drop down menu appears as this:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.tab{
font-family: arial, verdana, san-serif; 
font-size: 14px;
}
.asd
{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial, verdana, san-serif;
font-size: 13px; 
color:#4234ff;
}

/*****remove the list style****/
#nav {
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
list-style:none;
}   

/*****LI display inline *****/
#nav li {
float:left; 
display:block; 
width:100px;
background:#1E5B91;
position:relative;
z-index:500; 
margin:0 1px;
}

/*****parent menu*****/
#nav li a {
display:block; 
padding:8px 5px 0 5px; 
font-weight:700; 
height:23px; 
text-decoration:none; 
color:#ffffff;
text-align:center; 
color:#ffeecc;
}

#nav li a:hover 
{
color:#470020;
}

/* style for default selected value */ #nav a.selected {
color:#4234ff;
}
/* submenu */ #nav ul 
{
position:absolute; 
left:0; 
display:none; 
margin:0 0 0 -1px;
padding:0; 
list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li
{
width:100px; 
float:left; 
border-top:1px solid #fff;
}

/* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */ #nav ul a 
{
display:block; 
height:15px;
padding: 8px 5px; 
color:#ff7777
}

#nav ul a:hover 
{
text-decoration:underline;  
padding-left:15px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#nav li').hover(
function () {
//show its submenu
$('ul', this).slideDown(350);
}, 
function () {
//hide its submenu
$('ul', this).slideUp(350); 
}
);
});
</script>

<input type=hidden name=arav value="1*#*#*2"><ul id='nav'>
<li> <a href='#'>SHOP</a>
<ul>
<li style='background-color:#b0c4de;'><a href=http://LINK.com>Womens</a></li>
<li style='background-color:#bebebe;'><a href=http://LINK.com>Mens</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can we have it on jsfiddle please? How on earth would we be able to know what it looks like on your site if all it says is 404 Page not found??

Comment: Not sure, what you mean. CSS is Same Origin. You need to access the `iframe` Object to change it with JavaScript, but there is a Same Origin Policy Restriction as well. Please clarify.

Comment: @WilliamYang okay replaced it with the actual src.

Comment: Here's a start. http://jsfiddle.net/scXHp/ What't the problem again? I don't see menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IGNORE THIS:**

Your iframe z-index is the first problem (not sure why as the number is lower then the #nav). The other problem is your jquery code - the menu doesn't work and I get this error in Firefox 23.0.1  js console

```
reference error $ is not defined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnelson/krWS4/5/ - Here is your slide with the same css but changed javascript code (still JQ) and the z-index from your iframe removed.

**EDIT: ** Also [kimberlyfrommars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714389/kimberlyfrommars) please take note of these tips for your code.

1. Seperate all code (no style="[stuff ...]") and `<style>` together in the same doc ..makes coding harder for you.

   - Preferably put all styles into a seperate file for easier universal access (one style  for all pages instead of `<style>` in each page).
2. Whenever you are creating a jquery animation make sure you use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

   - Every time you hover over the SHOP ..an animation is queued ..even if the previous animation hasn't finished. So .stop() is the first thing called to remove any animation queues.

**EDIT:**

Remove

theme.css(line:585)

```
.strip {
overflow: hidden; <-- this
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
```

**AND**

theme.css(line: 728)

```
#main_nav {
min-width: 900px;
overflow: hidden; <--- this
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's still not working... Now I'm wondering if it's even the iframe that's the problem, because it's doing it to all the other pages at the same height as well. If you want to check out the source, it's: http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com

You seem like you know what you're talking about, so please help!

Comment: Take a look now ..there was a overflow: hidden; set on two <elements> clipping the menu bar. I've pointed out which ones on the previous post I made.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much! I knew it had something to do with the #main_nav but was sorta' hesitant about the .strip! Thanks!!

Comment: No problems :-) nice site.

Comment: thanks! haha it's been a pain in the ass so far but you just made it 1200x easier!

Comment: The only problem I'm having now, is that the .strip background (which is gray) isn't going all the way down on some of my custom pages (like the Blog page) since we got rid of the "overflow:hidden;" attribute. Any way we could fix this??

Comment: Its because you are using floats. Your #content (with strip added) is a block level element. Floats inside block level elements that only contains floats will collapse. 

Basically you should either apply `overflow: auto` to `<div id="content" class="strip">` or remove the `float: left;` from ul#entries li {} (from your Blog page).

Comment: That worked! Looks great, but now on the home page, there's a scroll bar inside of the content. Anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: Instead of overflow: auto; I added overflow: hidden; no scrollbar coming up and the background is working. Anything I should be aware of about this? Haha.